# Ant's sql task raw output

Tags: java, ant, task

Is there any way to execute SQL task in Ant without it parses the output?

I dont want the results converted to CSV.

I tried playing with:

> print, showheaders, showtrailers, keepformat, rawblobs

options but I did not got it

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you want the resultset output in a format other than csv - is that right?  What format do you want?

Comment: The default one, no format at all but what my database responses (in MySQl case, at least, columnated nice output)

Comment: The output format is determined by the client program rather than the database server - there's not really a default per se.  It sounds like your question is: "How can I get mysql format output from the Ant sql task?"  Is that right?

Comment: Yes. At least a similar one would be enough, like a columnated pretty print view. Is that possible, is not even monospaced/equal spaced.